# I cannot seem to receive images from my express API

Tags: javascript, api, express

So I am trying to retrieve images from my expressjs API and I cannot seem to actually retrieve anything, not locally or even remotely.

Here is the written code below :)

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'/public/')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/getImage/:folder/:imageName', function (req, res) {
  console.log(path.join(__dirname,'/',req.params.folder,'/',req.params.imageName));
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'/',req.params.folder,'/',req.params.imageName));
  res.end();
});
```

Have I written something wrong? Is there something I am missing?

here is the request http://localhost:3000/getImage/public/da4b9237bacccdf19c0760cab7aec4a8359010b0678f63452c5c1d428cd376dd82c55aa33a34e600.jpg

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE 
So it works when I remove res.end(), I'm assuming this is being executed before the image has fully been received?